# Too fast confirmation mail job with Devise and confirmable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I have a basic setup of rails and devise with the confirmable module.
I have overwritten the `send_devise_notification` to use the `ActionMailer` which uses `ActiveJob` for the delivery.

In my environment configs I have set `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq` so that all my ActiveJobs run on sidekiq.

```
def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
  devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver_later
end
```

Unfortunately it seems that sidekiq is too fast and tries to send the mail before the database transaction is done and therefore runs into a `Account with id = ... not found`. Sidekiq retries the job, obviously, and succeeds at some point.

Anyone with the same problem or idea how to solve this? The `wait` option for `deliver_later` is a no go.

Comment: Just FYI for people who come here through search. This is fixed in devise#4.1.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `devise-async` gem.

```
gem 'devise-async'
```

and add `:async` in User model as well:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :async, :confirmable # etc ...
end
```

See more details on gem [homepage](https://github.com/mhfs/devise-async/).

Comment: I need to use it? `send_devise_notification` is hooked `after_commit` in devise anyways and its  overwritten to use sidekq via ActiveJob/ActionMailer. I dont see much of a point to use this wrapper gem.